# Shor's algorithm weaknesses & uniqueness of close rational

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

I'm working through a problem set, and am stuck on the following problem:

> **a**) What can go wrong in Shor’s algorithm if Q (the dimension of the Quantum Fourier Transform) is not taken to be sufficiently large? Illustrate with an example.
>
> **b**) What can go wrong if the function, f, satisfies $f(p) = f(q)$ if the period $s$ divides $p − q$, but it’s not an “if and only if” (i.e., we could have $f(p) = f(q)$ even when $s$ doesn’t divide $p − q$)? Note that this does not actually happen for the function in Shor’s algorithm, but it could happen when attempting period finding on an arbitrary function. Illustrate with an example.
>
> **c**) What can go wrong in Shor’s algorithm if the integer $N$ to be factored is even (that is, one of the prime factors, $p$ and $q$, is equal to 2)? Illustrate with an example.
>
> **d**) Prove that there can be at most one rational $\frac{a}{b}$, with $a$ and $b$ positive integers, that’s at most $\epsilon$ away from a real number $x$ and that satisfies $b < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$. Explain how this relates to the choice, in Shor’s algorithm, to choose Q to be quadratically larger than the integer $N$ that we’re trying to factor.

I've been wrestling with it for a while, and my attempt so far is:

> a) When $s$ (the period) does not divide $Q$, a sufficiently large $Q$ ensures that the rational approximation to $\frac{k Q}{s}$ where $k$ is an integer is sufficiently close to determine a unique $s$.
>
> b) There might be more than one period $s$ associated with the function (something [like an acoustic beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics))), so it would be much more difficult to solve for one period individually.
>
> c) Completely lost....
>
> d) I supposed that there existed two different rationals such that $\mid{\frac{a_1}{b_1} - \frac{a_2}{b_2}}\mid> 0$ and tried to force a contradiction using the constraints $\mid\frac{a_\mu}{b_\mu}-x\mid \leq \epsilon$ and $b_\mu < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$, but couldn't get it to come out. Either I am making a stupid mistake and/or missing something simple (?).

I am really struggling to gain intuition for Shor's algorithm and its specific steps, so I'm very unconfident when trying to address parts (a) - (c). I'm stumped by (c) especially; isn't Shor's algorithm robust in the sense that it does not matter if $N$ is even or odd? If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding point c), this should be handled by classic preprocessing. What likely is the case for even $N$, that the period for numbers is off/not correctly computable.

I admit that these aren't the easiest questions, even when understanding Shor.

Comment: If a/b != c/d then a/b - c/d = (ad - bc) / bd has to be at least +-1/bd.

Answer (score 2):

For question c,

> c) What can go wrong in Shor’s algorithm if the integer $N$ to be factored is even (that is, one of the prime factors, $p$ and $q$, is equal to $2$)?

In order for the period-finding algorithm to work, there needs to be a period to find in the first place.

Let us do the modular exponentiation (repeated squaring) unitary $U_f$ on the second register:

$$U_{f}\sum^{N-1}_{x = 0}\vert x\rangle\vert 0\rangle = \vert x\rangle\vert a^{x}\text{ mod }N\rangle$$

Suppose we measure the second register and get a number, $y$.  It may be the case that, if $N=2p$, because $p$ has to be large, the first register collapses to *only one* number $x$ such that $y=a^x \mod N$.  Thus, there is no "collision" to which the QFT can find a period.

That is, doing a QFT on the pure state $\vert x\rangle$ with only one value, and then measuring, doesn't tell you anything.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding (c) -

Too see what can go wrong, we'll need to take a step back and look at Shor's Algorithm assumptions.

Basically, the algorithm says we need to pick a random $X$, find its order $r$, and finally calculate $X^\frac{r}{2} \pmod N$ to get information about $N$.

$N$ is of the form $2P$, thus by Chinese Remainder Theorm it will only have two roots modulo $N$, and they will have to be the trivial roots $1$ and $N-1$. That happens because $2$ has only one trivial root, unlike other primes.

Thus for any $X$ you may pick, $X^\frac{r}{2} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod N$, so you will always end up with the trivial roots, which are not enough for deriving factors of $N$ (not even the factor $2$!)

---

Reference - [vazirani lecture on Shor's Algorithm](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/f04quantum/notes/lec9.pdf)